# EJB 3.1 and NIO2: Monitoring the file system

Tags: ejb-3.1, nio2

I guess most of us agree, that NIO2 is a fine thing to make use of. Presumed you want to monitor some part of the file system for incoming xml - files it is an easy task now. But what if I want to integrate the things into an existing Java EE application so I don't have to start another service (app-server **AND** the one which monitors the file system)? 
So I have the heavy weight app-server with all the EJB 3.1 stuff and some kind of service monitoring the file system and take appropriate action once a file shows up. Interestingly the appropriate action is to create a Message and send it by JMS and it might be nice to integrate both into the app server.

I tried @Startup but deployment freezes (and I know that I shouldn't make use of I/O in there, was just a try). Anyhow ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a singleton that loads at startup and delegates the monitoring to an Asynchronous bean

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Initialiser {

    @EJB
    private FileSystemMonitor fileSystemMonitor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        String fileSystemPath = ....;
        fileSystemMonitor.poll(fileSystemPath);
    }

}
```

Then the Asynchronous bean looks something like this

```
@Stateless
public class FileSystemMonitor {

    @Asynchronous
    public void poll(String fileSystemPath) {
        WatchService watcher = ....;
        for (;;) {
            WatchKey key = null;
            try {
                key = watcher.take();
                for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                    WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();
                    if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW) {
                        continue; // If events are lost or discarded
                    }
                    WatchEvent<Path> watchEvent = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;

                    //Process files....

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            } finally {
                if (key != null) {
                    boolean valid = key.reset();
                    if (!valid) break; // If the key is no longer valid, the directory is inaccessible so exit the loop.
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well done, I'll try it ... Aside of the asynchronous aspect I did pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

Might help if you specified what server you're using, but have you considered implementing a JMX based service ? It's a bit more "neutral" than EJB, is more appropriate for a background service and has fewer restrictions.

Comment: Hi Nicolas,##first of all thx for your time. Currently we are using JBoss 7.1.1 but might switch to Glassfish 3.1. JMX definitely is an option but I'm wondering, how ESBs (like JBoss ESB) address this problem, are they using JMX as well?