# Issue invoking WatchService inside a singleton bean

Tags: java, jboss7.x, watchservice

we wanted to watch a file periodically for changes, we are using jboss 7 . Following is my code snippet. I initialized the watcher in the postconstruct method of singleton bean and scheduled a method to poll watch events. I could observe the changes when i modify the file very first time, however the subsequent modifications to the file are not recieved . Can anyone please let me know what could be the issue

```
  @Startup
  @ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
  @Interceptors(NonThrowingPostConstructInterceptor.class)
  @Singleton
  @Service
  @LocalBinding(jndiBinding=IHeartBeatProducerService.JNDI_LOCAL_BINDING)
 public class HeartBeatProducerService extends EMSingletonService implements IHeartBeatProducerService{

@EJB(mappedName=IMessageService.JNDI_LOCAL_BINDING)
public IMessageService messageService;

@EJB(mappedName=ICommandExecutionService.JNDI_LOCAL_BINDING)
public ICommandExecutionService commandService;

private final static String LAST_OPERATION_COMPLETED="Last Operation Completed";

private final static String STATUS="Status"; 

private WatchService watcher;

private Path dir;

private String concServer; 

public static final String TOPIC="foo";

private IMLogger logger = new IMLogger("foo");

private String content=null; 

@PostConstruct
@Override
public void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.init();
    try {


        watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        dir=Paths.get("/shared/foo");
        dir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
        logger.entering(0, IHeartBeatProducerService.class.getSimpleName(), "Initializing Heart Beat", new String[]{"Entered"});

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Schedule(second="*/10", minute = "*", hour="*")
private void checkStatus()
{
    logger.entering(0, IHeartBeatProducerService.class.getSimpleName(), "Checking Status", new String[]{"Entered"});
    final String[] command={"pidof","server"};
    commandService.run(command, null, false);
    concServer=(commandService.getExitCode()==0)?"UP":"DOWN";
    if(concServer.equals("UP"))
    {
        watch();
    }
    else
    {
        content="foo:Failed";
    }
    produce();
}


public void watch()
{       
        logger.entering(0, IHeartBeatProducerService.class.getSimpleName(), "Entering watch()", new String[]{"Entered"});
        WatchKey key = null;

        try 
        {           
         key = watcher.take();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {               
            logger.error(HeartBeatProducerService.class.getSimpleName(),"Interupted Exception " +  e.getMessage());
        }

        for ( WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents())
        {
            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

            logger.info(HeartBeatProducerService.class.getSimpleName(),"Watch Event :" + kind.name()); 

            if(kind.name().equals("OVERFLOW"))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if(kind.name().equals("ENTRY_MODIFY"))
            {
                Path concLog = (Path) event.context();

                logger.info(HeartBeatProducerService.class.getSimpleName(),"Modified File Name:" + concLog.getFileName()); 

                if(concLog.endsWith("current_status.txt"))
                {
                    logger.info(HeartBeatProducerService.class.getSimpleName(), "Reading Status");                  
                    readStatus();
                }
            }

        }

        boolean valid = key.reset();

        if ( !valid)
        {               
            logger.error(HeartBeatProducerService.class.getSimpleName(),"Key Unregistered"); 
        }
}





private void parse(String output)
{       
    // parse file contents
}

private void readStatus() {

    //read status and parse()

}
private void produce() 
{

    try {

        messageService.publish(TOPIC, content, PublishType.ASync);

    } catch (MessageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

There is already a link explaining the same with @Asynchronous tag ([EJB 3.1 and NIO2: Monitoring the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381274/ejb-3-1-and-nio2-monitoring-the-file-system)) . however I need to know what could be wrong in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your watch method needs to run in an infinite loop. What's happening now is that after

```
     try {           
       key = watcher.take();
     }
```

you process the event and then the watch() method is finished. Try the effect of

```
     for(;;) {
```

before the above lines, ending the for block after the validity check. Did you see the example at [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)?

Comment: but I have scheduled the watch() for every 10 seconds .. see the checkStatus method.

Comment: Saravana, I didn't see your annotations. I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm wondering what happens when you call take() on a WatchService that's already blocked on a take() call? Unfortunately I don't have a JBoss installation available to try and reproduce your problem. Perhaps it would be a good idea to try it without the @Schedule annotation and see if that works as expected (in a loop)? - John