# EJB and WatchService

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, nio, ejb-3.1

I developp an application on a JBoss 7.1 which have to monitor a directory of the fileSystem.
For this purpose, I write some code which looks like what I found in this post :[EJB 3.1 and NIO2: Monitoring the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381274/ejb-3-1-and-nio2-monitoring-the-file-system).
So I write a session ejb PollingServiceImpl with an asynchronous method watching the path I have to monitor and an @StartUp Ejb which call the session EJB. 
Here is my code for the PollingService :

```
@Stateless
public class PollingServiceImpl {
private Path       fichiersXmlPath=Paths.get("/media/sf_DossierPartage/IsidoreJaxb/specXML/fichiersXml");

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public PollingServiceImpl() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Asynchronous
public void pollForXmlMessage()  {

     WatchService service=null;
    // Vérification que le path est un répertoire
    try {
        Boolean isFolder = (Boolean) Files.getAttribute(fichiersXmlPath,
                "basic:isDirectory", LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
        if (!isFolder) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("le path : " + fichiersXmlPath + " n'est pas un répertoire");
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("le path : " + fichiersXmlPath + " n'est pas un répertoire");

    }

    System.out.println("Répertoire observé: " + fichiersXmlPath);

    // On obtient le système de fichier du chemin
    FileSystem fs = fichiersXmlPath.getFileSystem ();

    // We create the new WatchService using the new try() block
    try{ service = fs.newWatchService();

        //On enregistre le chemin dans le watcher
        // On surveille les opérations de création
        fichiersXmlPath.register(service, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

        // Beginning of the infinite loop

        for(;;) {
            WatchKey key = service.take();

            // Sortir les événements de la queue
            Kind<?> kind = null;
            for(WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : key.pollEvents()) {
                // on teste le type de l'événement
                kind = watchEvent.kind();

                // If les événements sont perdus
                if (StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW == kind) {
                    continue; //loop

                // Si c'est un événement de création
                } else if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE == kind) {
                    // A new Path was created 
                    Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent).context();
                    // Output
                    System.out.println("nouveau chemin : " + newPath +" numKey "+key.toString() );

                    // buisness process
                }
            }

            if (key != null) {
                boolean valid = key.reset();
                if (!valid) break; // If the key is no longer valid, the directory is inaccessible so exit the loop.
            }

        }

    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            service.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


}
```

and here is the code for the startp ejb :
    @Singleton
@Startup
public class Initialiser {

```
        @EJB
        private PollingServiceImpl pollingService;

        public enum States {BEFORESTARTED, STARTED, PAUSED, SHUTTINGDOWN};

        private States state;


        @PostConstruct
        public void initialize() {

        state = States.BEFORESTARTED;

       pollingService.pollForXmlMessage();
         state = States.STARTED;
         System.out.println("ETAT : "+state.toString());
        }


        @PreDestroy
        public void terminate() {

        state = States.SHUTTINGDOWN;

        System.out.println("Shut down in progress");

        }

        public States getState() {

        return state;

        }

        public void setState(States state) {

        this.state = state;

        }

    }
```

Everything looks fine and the watcher works well but I have two problems :
1) Some warnings appears on the console like this :
    [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id
    0:ffff7f000101:-51121f7e:53b7f879:9 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
    15:12:14,522 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108:
    CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff7f000101:-51121f7e:53b7f879:9 aborting with
    1 threads active!
    15:12:14,522 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: 
    TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] 
    successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000101:-51121f7e:53b7f879:9

2) The server refuse to shutdown : apparently the thread launched at start up don't stop. I have read in some posts that i have to stop the method pollForXmlMessage in the @PreDestroy method of the Initializer ejb but I don't know how i can make that or if there is another solution.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a template of the solution:

```
public class Service{
    private volotile boolean isCancelled = false;

    public void startService()
    {   //infinit loop:
        while(!isCancelled) {}
    }

    public void stopService()
    {
        isCancelled = true;
    }
}
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ServiceStarter{

    Service service;
    @EJB ServiceAsyncWorker asyncWorker;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        service = new Service(...);
        asyncWorker.startService(service);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void destroy()
    {
        service.stopService();
    }
}
@Singleton
public class ServiceAsyncWorker{
    @Asynchronous
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void startService(Service service){
        service.startService();
    }
}
```

Comment: I implementing your solution & it works but I get the following exception at the end of the process. 2016-04-05 17:52:00,332 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 5) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component DirectoryMonitorService for method public void za.co.fnb.cii.relandheir.batch.inputprocessor.service.DirectoryMonitorService.watchDirectory(): javax.ejb.ConcurrentAccessTimeoutException: JBAS014373: EJB 3.1 PFD2 4.8.5.5.1 concurrent access timeout on org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation@162c9ba6 - could not obtain lock within 5000MILLISECONDS

Answer (score 0):

Every EJB method executes in a transaction context. 
If your method never returns JBoss informs you about a very long transaction that is probably hung.

Instead I would recommend moving this into a resource adapter that invokes a MDB on events like new files. 
http://robertpanzer.github.io/blog/2014/inboundra-nointfmdbs.html shows an example with a JavaEE7 style MDB but porting this down to JavaEE 6 and therefore JBoss 7 should be trivial.

Comment: Thx you for your answer Robert! Finally I've found another solution. I implement a WebListener which start a thred to poll the filesystem when the web context is initialized and kill the thread when the app close. Apparently this works quite well...
I'll take a look at mdbs when i'd have more time...

Comment: Great! But please keep in mind that starting threads in Java EE components except resource adapters is strongly discouraged. It may run in your target environment but may fail on another server.

Comment: woo! Does it mean that i will certainly have problems when deploying the app on production server?

Comment: No, I only meant when you change the AppServer vendor. Like switching from JBoss to WebSphere. It doesn't have to lead to problems but it could, because you are moving outside the Java EE specs.

Comment: ok thx for your help! I don't know mdbs for the moment but i will learn... I'm an enthousiast but quite new JEE programmer ^^

Comment: @marcoG I'm trying to do the same thing, do you mind sharing your code to your solution, please